# how to restore bios boot setting?

Tags: windows-7, boot, bios

I have a hp probook 4540s, I was trying to manipulate booting process and I did the following:

1 used xboot tool to boot from usb HDD, and I mounted ultimate boot cd on it

2 I logged into ultimate boot cd and selected HDD management then smart boot tool, I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> which is to duplicate boot

Now what I got is pxe exiting (f30) error.

I can log into windows by booting from usb HDD then escape or select to boot from widows cd and when it comes to `press any key to boot from dvd` i press nothing

How to restore bios boot setting?

Comment: There is normally a restore default and/or just by "updating" the firmware the settings change.

Comment: i did that, but still the same problem,

Answer (score 0):

For now I don't see anything what might be connected with BIOS of your laptop. [HP suggests](http://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c00034791) that you should press <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>F1</kbd> during the welcoming screen and you should be redirected to BIOS. Then you should specify the boot order and configure your machine to load up from HDD first. Save recently made changes and quit and you should be good to go.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the order, i revised it

Comment: i used easybcd and set the drive C:/ to boot ,

Comment: now i dont have booting problem , but still i have that pxe exiting error ,its not affecting a thing, but any idea how i can get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure you're getting ``F30`` error not ``3F0``? Here is a [link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware-and-Upgrade-Questions/Hard-Disk-3F0/td-p/1354307) to ``3F0`` error solution.

Comment: From what I have found PXE exiting error appear when system tries to boot from network card instead of HDD.

Comment: i think i knew the problem now, i have 100mb windows partition is set to be primary partition, and the C partition is the system and boot partition, any ideas how to set the 100mb windows partition as boot&system

Comment: @dimmu this ``100mb`` partition is created automatically by Windows 7 during the custom installation process with ``bootmgr``, meaning it is initially a boot partition. I think that I'm missing something. The only way to troubleshoot the boot functionally would be to perform a [startup repair](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/927392).

Comment: problem was solved when i sat the 100mb partition as active

Comment: @dimmu glad you've found a solution. You didn't mention anywhere that deactivated the partition. The answer would be much more easier to guess if you mentioned exactly what you've done.

Comment: well i didnt deactivate it,, i just tried to check that, it happened all by itself, i guess when i was playing with the smart boot tool:D